# Fastify Route Params required is not honored

Tags: fastify

I have a route something like this:

```
    // collection GET
    fastify.route({
        method: 'GET',
        url: `${constants.EXTERNAL_PATH}/:serviceName/:collectionName/account/:accountId`,
        schema: {
            description: 'Get all documents from the specified table for the specified service database and account.',
            summary: 'Get all documents from the specified table.',
            tags: ['persistence'],
            headers: {
                $ref: 'authorization-user#'
            },
            params:{
                type: 'object',
                properties: {
                    serviceName:    { type: 'string' },
                    collectionName: { type: 'string' },
                    accountId:      { type: 'string' }
                },
                required: ['serviceName', 'collectionName', 'accountId'],
            },
            response: {
                200: {
                    properties: {
                        'documents': {
                            description: 'All the retrieved documents from the specified table for the specified service database and account.',
                            type: 'array',
                            items: {
                                $ref: 'persistence-response-doc#',                  
                            }
                        },
                    },
                },
                '4xx': {
                    $ref: 'error-response#',
                    description: 'Error response'
                }
            }
        },
        handler: async (request, reply) => {
           // Logic goes here //
        }
    });
```

Now my expectation was that:

This should work:

```
http://localhost:9011/persistence/external/myservice/mycollection/account/my_actn_id
As it has the service as myservice, collection as mycollection and accountId as my_actn_id
```

However this should fail with a route error (say when I am missing the :accountId, which is **required**):

```
http://localhost:9011/persistence/external/myservice/mycollection/account/  <== should fail
```

However both are passing, returning same collection results.

What am I missing here?

Thanks,
Pradip

Comment: Without the accountId you have a different route i.e. to ${constants.EXTERNAL_PATH}/:serviceName/:collectionName/account/

Comment: I see. So does it means the last part of the route I can not say like :params_id?
So if I would have something like:
${constants.EXTERNAL_PATH}/:serviceName/:collectionName/account/:accountId/something
Where 'something' is just a fixed string, would that work?
Thanks.

Comment: You are mixing the validation rules with the routing ones. The validation doesn't happen if the router did not found the route. In fact, if a piece of the URL is missing, the router will reply 404 and not 400

Comment: Ok. Does it mean the params validation we should not put in schema section of the route? If so - what is the best place/practice to put the params validation vs the body/response validations?
https://www.fastify.io/docs/v2.2.x/Validation-and-Serialization/#validation  I was trying to follow actually.

Comment: @Pradip Sorry I don't know the answer to your '/something' question. Perhaps create a route to ${constants.EXTERNAL_PATH}/:serviceName/:collectionName/account/ that returns an error "Account ID missing".

Comment: @Frazer: Yeah. I am thinking in same line. Another route for error handling.
Then tell me one thing:
E.g. I want to have one collection GET and another instance GET.

So I can NOT have something like: 
${constants.EXTERNAL_PATH}/:serviceName/:collectionName/account/:accountId/:documentId
; where documentId is optional (not present during collection GET, present during instance GET).
If I need it, I have two options: 

1. One route without :documentId, another with :documentId (instance GET).

2. pass the documentId as query (/?documentId=<>).

Which one is REST API best practice?

Answer (score 0):

**Add a minLenght**

```
fastify.route({
        method: 'GET',
        url: `${constants.EXTERNAL_PATH}/:serviceName/:collectionName/account/:accountId`,
        schema: {
            description: 'Get all documents from the specified table for the specified service database and account.',
            summary: 'Get all documents from the specified table.',
            tags: ['persistence'],
            headers: {
                $ref: 'authorization-user#'
            },
            params:{
                type: 'object',
                properties: {
                    serviceName:    { type: 'string', minLength: 1 },
                    collectionName: { type: 'string', minLength: 1 },
                    accountId:      { type: 'string', minLength: 1 }
                },
                required: ['serviceName', 'collectionName', 'accountId'],
            },
            response: {
                200: {
                    properties: {
                        'documents': {
                            description: 'All the retrieved documents from the specified table for the specified service database and account.',
                            type: 'array',
                            items: {
                                $ref: 'persistence-response-doc#',                  
                            }
                        },
                    },
                },
                '4xx': {
                    $ref: 'error-response#',
                    description: 'Error response'
                }
            }
        },
        handler: async (request, reply) => {
           // Logic goes here //
        }
    });
```